My IV summary in R reports as NA after imputing with mice and matching with Amelia
After imputing and matching, my IV of interest returns NAs.
I have a dataset that is mostly complete but for a couple of variables - coord1D and cinc. I used the following code to create my independent variable, treaty:
air6_1 <- air6_1  %>%
  mutate(treaty = case_when(hague >= 1 ~ 1,
                             geneva >= 1 ~ 1,
                            protocol >=1 ~ 1))

I used the following code to impute the missing data using mice:
imputed.datasets <- mice(air6_1, m = 5)

and then the following code for nearest neighbor matching using matchthem:
matched.datasets <- matchthem(air ~ coord1D + v2x_polyarchy + NATO + cinc,
                              datasets = imputed.datasets,
                              approach = 'within',
                              method = 'nearest',
                              caliper = 0.05,
                              ratio = 1)

From the survey library, I tried to run a logistic model across my imputed datasets with the following code:
matched.models <- with(matched.datasets,
                       glm(air ~ treaty + v2x_polyarchy + NATO + cinc, family = quasibinomial()),
                       cluster = TRUE)

The code runs smoothly, but when I enter summary(matched.models), my IV of interest - treaty - returns 'NA' rather than a coefficient, as below:
term          estimate std.error statistic p.value  nobs
   <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1 (Intercept)   -0.0296      0.317  -0.0935    0.926   298
** 2 treaty        NA          NA      NA        NA       298**
 3 v2x_polyarchy  0.00423     0.476   0.00889   0.993   298
 4 NATO           0.0861      0.442   0.195     0.846   298
 5 cinc           0.173       1.42    0.122     0.903   298
 6 (Intercept)    0.0228      0.319   0.0714    0.943   298
** 7 treaty        NA          NA      NA        NA       298**
 8 v2x_polyarchy -0.0608      0.480  -0.127     0.899   298
 9 NATO          -0.0655      0.427  -0.153     0.878   298
10 cinc           0.132       1.41    0.0939    0.925   298

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Forgive me if I am not posting correctly - I honestly don't understand how to complete the dput requirement with imputed datasets, even after watching a 10-minute YouTube video.

In your case_when, you need to supply a default value for treaty as the defualt is NA.
